# pthread C++ in Centos no run

Tags: c++, pthreads

This is my code:

```
void* task1(void* unused)
{
    try {               
      cout << "Run Thread" << endl;     
    }catch (const char* msg) {
      cout << msg << endl;
    }    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    try {
      pthread_t thread_id;    
      int res = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &task1, NULL);
      cout << res << std::endl;   
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);      
    }catch (const char* msg) {
      cout << msg << endl;
    }

}
```

- In Ubuntu Code RUN.
- In CentOS Code NOT RUN, if my use `pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);` code is run but can waiting `pthread` complete. I try `pthread_tryjoin_np` but code not run.
- **Please help me run code in centos is no wating**

Answer (score 3):

If the program `main()` exits before the thread actually starts (and runs to the point `cout << ...`), the thread will be terminated and not continue to run.

I.e. you need to wait with `pthread_join()` before the `main()` exits.

The case in Ubuntu is a pure coincidence, that the thread manages to print the line before it is terminated by the C++ runtime after the `main()` exits.

If you do not want to wait because you want to start multiple threads, you can use thread pool (array of threads). First you start all of them, and then you `pthread_join()` wait for all of them to finish.

Also, if the `pthread_join()` blocks although the thread terminated, make sure you created the thread as joinable. That is the default, so make sure that you do not explicitly set the thread attributes to `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`.

To be absolutely sure, you can provide thread create attributes explicitly and ensure that the thread is created as joinable:

```
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &task1, NULL);
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
```

(error handling not included)

Answer (score 1):

Why you do not use C ++ 11? Standard library (STL) have the opportunity to develop crossplatform applications with threads. You can test on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void task1(int used)
{
    std::cout << "Run Thread " << used << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    std::thread thr(task1,1);
    thr.join();
    return 0;
}
```

OR

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

bool bThread = false;
void task1(int used)
{
    std::cout << "Run Thread " << used << std::endl;
    bThread = true;
}

int main() 
{
    std::thread thr(task1,1);
    try
    {
        thr.detach();
        while (!bThread) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
    catch(...) { return 1; }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not using thr.join() instead? Btw. the bool should imho be set at the end of task and not before the cout, because then you still risk that the print will not occur (and in general, it should be synchronized or at least volatile). Besides, programs usually return 0 on success (or better yet EXIT_SUCCESS) and 1 (EXIT_FAILURE) on error, not "false" (which happens to be 0).

Comment: I agree. But Is example.